# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '1.2.3.4' (10060)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, remote-access, remote

I've tried to look for a solution and there are many similar questions but somehow none of the solutions are working.

I have a laravel app running on one of my ubuntu servers at 1.2.3.4 IP. I installed mysql and everything is working fine for the app on the same server as the database.

Now, I want to access the database on 1.2.3.4 from another server with a.b.c.d IP.

*https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql*

I followed the instructions given in the above link.

1. I changed bind_address to 0.0.0.0 in my conf file.
2. Created a user `CREATE USER 'test_user'@'a.b.c.d' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
3. Assigned appropriate permissions and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
4. Open access on 3306.
   On `ufw status`, I'm getting this response for 3306 IP:

```
    3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere 
    3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
```

But when I try to access the database `mysql -u test_user -h 1.2.3.4 -p`
I'm getting `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '1.2.3.4' (10060)`

Maybe I'm missing some step(s) or not using IP addresses correctly. Can anyone please assist? Any way to identify the actual issue behind the error?

Comment: After change bind to 0.0.0.0 did you restart the service?

Comment: Yes, I did. I even restarted the server.

Comment: Try to create user w/o IP (can be same name) and check again

Comment: Upon testing, I realized the connection is not established at port 3306. Maybe it's something to do with my hosting provider. I'll check with them first.